# Let $B$ definite positive matrix and $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $Bu$. Show that $\cos \theta \geq \frac{1}{M}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and let $v,u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose that $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $Bu$, that is,

$$\cos \theta =\frac{v^{T}(Bu)}{\left\|v\right\|\left\|Bu\right\|}$$

Suppose that $\left\|B\right\|\left\|B^{-1}\right\|\leq M$ where $M>0$. Show that $\cos\theta \geq \frac{1}{M}
$.

**Remark:** In [this link](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/teaching/w09/666.w09/666miscfiles/solnsasss02W09.pdf) there are two proofs but assume that $B$ is symmetric. I need a proof that does not require that $B$ be symmetric.

Comment: If $B$ is not symmetric, how do you define $B$ to be definite positive?

Comment: If you choose $v \bot Bu$ then $\cos \theta = 0$.

Comment: @MingfengZhao, use $S=\frac{1}{2}(B+B^{\top})$ for any matrix to mimic what we know to do with a symmetric one: 'cuz for the quadratic form one has $x^{\top}Bx=x^{\top}Sx$.